# parallel foreach strange behavior

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I've code the runs more or less the following construct -
and when ParallelRunner gets the delegate function testFunc it hangs ,
However if instead of providing a delegate I write the function explicitly inside the ParallelRunner method it works fine.

Note that this exact test method works, but a very similar code running under IIS ( in a background thread ) fails , and once I remove the testFunc delegate and explicitly write its code in ParallelRunner , or even call TestCondition directly ( without a delegate ) it works fine.

Any idea what could cause this strange behavior ?

```
  interface I { }

        class A : I { }
        class B :I { }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestParallelWithDelegate()
        {
            var list = new List<I>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    list.Add(new A());

                }
                else
                {
                    list.Add(new B());
                }


            }

            var bag = new ConcurrentBag<I>();

            Func<I, bool> testFunc = TestCondition;

            ParallelRunner(list,bag,testFunc);

            Console.WriteLine($"terminated with delegate bag size = {bag.Count}");

        }
        private static bool TestCondition(I i)
        {
            return !(i is A);
        }


        void ParallelRunner(List<I> list, ConcurrentBag<I> bag, Func<I,bool> testFunc = null)
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(list, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 3 },
                x =>
                {
                    if (testFunc == null || testFunc(x))
                    {
                        bag.Add(x);

                    }
                });

        }
```

Comment: You might be losing your variable, though I don't work with parallel for each very often. Try this: above your parallel.ForEach, add in `var testFunc2 = testFunc;` and then modify your loop to execute `testFunc2`. Does that make a difference?

Comment: In the actual code the testFunc is a static method in some class, so how could it be lost? 
I'll try anyways and see.. thanks

Comment: I think it has to do with the scope of how long the `testFunc` variable exists and correctly points to your static method. That might not be your case here - did you try out my suggestion?

Comment: Ye, it hangs.. I think it may have to do with the fact that delegate sent as testFunc is a static method in a class whose static constructor contains the code above...
When I debug I see that indeed it works till a point but then stops. I wonder why that static method is within the scope part of the time, and then stops as you suggest. any idea ?

Comment: If it's just hanging, check out this - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/static-constructor-deadlocks/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll find a way around it